# Is there software similar to Jupyter but does not run on browser

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Is there a software that is similar to Jupyter notebook but without the browser or how to run the notebook but not on a browser. I like the fact that Jupyter can write code in bits and run to see results and graphs can be displayed.

Comment: Jupyter has a couple of console modes, one with its own `qt` console, the other using system window.  When you see answers with `IN/OUT` line markings, those are `ipython` sessions.

Answer (score 2):

You can download [Atom](https://atom.io/) (an open-source text editor by GitHub) and install the [Hydrogen](https://atom.io/packages/hydrogen) extension to get a Jupyter kernel in your text editor. It runs as a native application and not in your browser.

If you're willing to pay ($89.00/year as of July 2022, unless you qualify for a [special offer](https://www.jetbrains.com/dataspell/buy/#discounts)), you can also use [JetBrains DataSpell](https://www.jetbrains.com/dataspell/), which is a native (i.e., non-web) application with an integrated Jupyter environment:

[image: DataSpell UI screenshot, from the JetBrains website]

*Image from the JetBrains DataSpell website, linked above.*